# I'm able to go to other towns on ACNL, but one of my friends can't visit my town?

Tags: technical-issues, animal-crossing-new-leaf

Like the title says, I'm able to visit other towns, and other people can visit mine perfectly fine. However, a friend of mine is having trouble visiting my town. She keeps getting an error (018-0510), and she even looked it up. This is the [error on the support website](http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/wfc/en_na/ds/results.jsp?error_code=018-0510&system=3DS&locale=en_US)

And both of us are able to connect to the Access Point just fine.

She is also able to visit other towns, but when we try to connect in my town, this error appears on the bottom screen.

Is anyone else also experiencing this, or does anyone have any ideas or solutions?

Comment: Did either of you change hardware recently?  Do both of you have each other listed as Friends in the nintendo friend manager?

Comment: Have both of you updated your games recently? Both of you should completely restart your DSs (don't just close the lid & put it in sleep mode).

Answer (score 1):

You are experiencing a NAT issue. Your friend's router may be set to a Moderate or Strict NAT setting. If they can, they should change it to be equivalent, or more open setting, using the router settings.

See [this link](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/12472) for more information.

Hope this helps!